# Need to get the Index of a XML node with specific child in groovy

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, xml-parsing

I am new to groovy scripting and I am having a hard time with this issue. I need the index of a body element in which is a child element with an error message. I tried using `findIndexValues()`but I am not getting the result I need

In this example my code should return index 0 and 2 .

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <Response>
    <body>
      <success>false</success>
      <errors>
        <statusCode>INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS</statusCode>
        <message>Wrong E-Mail</message>
        <fields>EMail</fields>
      </errors>
      <created>false</created>
    </body>
     <body>
      <id>0015r00000DiP5HAAV</id>
      <success>true</success><errors/>
      <created>false</created>
    </body>
    <body>
      <success>false</success>
      <errors>
        <statusCode>INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS</statusCode>
        <message>Wrong E-Mail</message>
        <fields>EMail</fields>
      </errors>
      <created>false</created>
    </body><httpHeaders/>
    <httpStatusCode>200</httpStatusCode>
    <referenceId>UpdateAccount</referenceId>
  </Response>
</root>
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps as

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
    '''<root>
  <Response>
    <body>
      <success>false</success>
      <errors>
        <statusCode>INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS</statusCode>
        <message>Wrong E-Mail</message>
        <fields>EMail</fields>
      </errors>
      <created>false</created>
    </body>
     <body>
      <id>0015r00000DiP5HAAV</id>
      <success>true</success><errors/>
      <created>false</created>
    </body>
    <body>
      <success>false</success>
      <errors>
        <statusCode>INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS</statusCode>
        <message>Wrong E-Mail</message>
        <fields>EMail</fields>
      </errors>
      <created>false</created>
    </body><httpHeaders/>
    <httpStatusCode>200</httpStatusCode>
    <referenceId>UpdateAccount</referenceId>
  </Response>
</root>''')

def bodyIndices = root.Response.body.findIndexValues({ b -> b.errors.message.size() > 0 })

print(bodyIndices)
```